# In python, what does script mean?

Tags: python

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", first
print "Your second variable is:", second
print "Your third variable is:", third
```

basically, does script here mean the file of the programm? like ex14.py?

im complete new to python and prgramming...if this question sound stupid to you all.

Comment: Try running it using the command line along with some arguments.

Comment: yes. my guess is script means the .py file. just want to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

Running it with the arguments: `1 2 3`

**Output:**

```
The script is called: E:\Proyectos\Eclipse\Python\Test\__init__.py
Your first variable is: 1
Your second variable is: 2
Your third variable is: 3
```

The first line prints the script name. Quoting Python Docs:

> ... argv[0] is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not).

The following 3 lines just prints the arguments I passed `1 2 3`.